# Java parsing from escaped json string

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

There are many threads related to this, but I can't solve my issue.

I get this string from parsing an iterable using GSON.

```
Iterable<ParametrosProveedores> proveedoresList;

proveedoresList = proveedoresRepository.findAll(); //From spring repository

String jsonString = gson.toJson(proveedoresList);
```

jsonString value is:

```
[{\"id\":1,\"proveedor\":\"CALIXTA\",\"unaVia\":true,\"dosVias\":true,\"plazasSi\":\"todas\",\"plazasNo\":\"\",\"turnoUnaVia\":false,\"turnoDosVias\":false},{\"id\":2,\"proveedor\":\"MOVILE\",\"unaVia\":true,\"dosVias\":true,\"plazasSi\":\"51,52\",\"plazasNo\":\"\",\"turnoUnaVia\":false,\"turnoDosVias\":false},{\"id\":3,\"proveedor\":\"TWILIO\",\"unaVia\":true,\"dosVias\":true,\"plazasSi\":\"todas\",\"plazasNo\":\"51\",\"turnoUnaVia\":false,\"turnoDosVias\":false},{\"id\":4,\"proveedor\":\"OTRO\",\"unaVia\":true,\"dosVias\":true,\"plazasSi\":\"todas\",\"plazasNo\":\"\",\"turnoUnaVia\":false,\"turnoDosVias\":false}]
```

Which is a json array. Is there really no way to parse from that string without removing escapes manually?

All I want to do is:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = parseFrom(jsonString);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `Gson.fromJson(String, Class)`?

Comment: `ParametrosProveedores[] data = gson.fromJson(jElement, ParametrosProveedores[].class);`

Comment: `jsonString.replace("\\", "");`

would replace all the escaped characters with nothing i think, which is better than as you said manually doing it

Comment: @scigs that's what I meant by manually, I don't want to do that, but seems like that's what I'm going go to since noone else understood my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a generic in the form of an `Iterable<T>`, you may need to use:

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(proveedoresList, typeOfSrc);
```

Where `typeOfSrc` is the type of your `proveedoresList`. that way `gson` knows how to serialize the object properly.